# POSTing data serverside AND execute javascript code on submitting a form

Tags: javascript, forms, post

My goal is to upload some images to a server and provide them with a description.

On clicking an upload button, this is what I want to happen:

> 1) a javascript function dynamically adds a form to get a description
>   of the images.
>
> 2) on submitting the form:
>
> ```
>  a) the description entered in the form must be available $_POST['description'] at server side.
>  b) the images are sent to the server using an XMLHttpRequest
> ```

In the code I wrote the description is not available `$_POST['description']`.
When i remove the check `if(!isset($_POST['description']))`, the imagefiles are perfectly uploaded.
This is my code:

javascript code

```
upload.onclick = uploadPrompt;

// dynamically add a form
function uploadPrompt () {
    // fileQueue is an array containing all images that need to be uploaded
    if (fileQueue.length < 1) {
        alert("There are no images available for uploading.");
    } else {
        var inputDescription = document.createElement("input");
        inputDescription.className = "promptInput";
        inputDescription.type = "text";
        inputDescription.name = "description";

        var inputButton = document.createElement("button");
        inputButton.id = "promptInputButton";
        inputButton.type = "submit";
        inputButton.innerHTML = "Start uploading";

        var promptForm = document.createElement("form");
        promptForm.method = "post";
        promptForm.action = "upload.php";
        promptForm.onsubmit = uploadQueue;
        promptForm.id = "promptForm";
        promptForm.appendChild(inputDescription);
        promptForm.appendChild(inputButton);

        document.body.appendChild(promptForm);
    }
}

function uploadQueue(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    elementToBeRemoved = document.getElementById("promptForm");
    elementToBeRemoved.parentElement.removeChild(elementToBeRemoved);

    while (fileQueue.length > 0) {
        var item = fileQueue.pop();
        // item.file is the actual image data
        uploadFile(item.file);
    }
}

function uploadFile (file) {
    if (file) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('image',file);

        xhr.upload.addEventListener("error", function (ev) {
            console.log(ev);
        }, false);

        xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");

        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);

        xhr.send(fd);
    }
}
```

php code upload.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_POST['description'])) {
    echo "upload:fail\n";
    echo "message:No scene was specified";
    exit();
}


if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "uploads/" . $_POST['description'] . "/" . $_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        echo "upload:fail\n";
        }
    else {
        echo "upload:succes\n";
    }
    exit();
}

exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd really advise against creating your own asynchronous file upload functionality when there is a plethora of developers who have already programmed the same thing better. Check out these options:

- [Blueimp's jQuery file uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)
- [Uploadifive](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/implementing-uploadifive/) (Uploadify's HTML5 implementation)

I've used these two before and they work very well. For BlueImp, you can use this option to send additional form data:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
   formData: $('.some_form').serialize()
});
```

The above captures a form and serializes its inputs. Alternatively, you can populate an array or object using specific values (i.e. from specific elements in your DOM):

```
var array = new Array();
$('.description').each(function() {
   array[this.id] = this.value;
});
```

You'd use IDs to link your files and descriptions.

Comment: I realize my code is rubbish and I am aware of the options you suggested. Though the uploading is only a single part of the application I'm trying to make. The 'serialize()' method you suggested helped me a lot! Thanks!!

Comment: Is there anything else you need help with? Otherwise you can mark this question as closed by accepting an answer - it'll help your acceptance rating